# How to make an AJAX request to jsFiddle's echo api using Ext.Ajax?

Tags: ajax, json, extjs, request, jsfiddle

I'm trying to make a simple AJAX call to jsFiddle's JSON echo api using `Ext.Ajax`. It makes the request successfully, but the object returned is empty, *not* the JSON object I send (which it should be).

Code:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    jsonData: { foo: 'bar' },
    success: function(resp) {
        console.log('success!');
        console.log(Ext.decode(resp.responseText)); //empty object..? why?
    },
    failure: function(resp) {
        console.log('failure!');
    },
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nANE7/

How come the response is just an empty object? Where's the foobar JSON information that it's meant to echo back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    params: { 
        json: Ext.encode(
            {
                param1:'bar'
            }
        ) 
    },
    success: function(resp) {
        console.log('success!');
        console.log( resp );
        console.log(Ext.decode(resp.responseText)); //empty object..? why?
    },
    failure: function(resp) {
        console.log('failure!');
    },
});
```